# Where can i find /data/data folder in my android phone?

Tags: android

I wanted to know that the /data/data/my.package.name/databases folder is situated in My phone memory or in the SD card? In both the cases, please tell me the exact location...
Please help..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a programming question? else, you'd probably better ask on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save in the **internal storage space**.
the exact location you said is right.

> my.package.name --> for example like: com.demo

ps: if your phone is not rooted, this folder maybe you don't have permission.

Answer (score 0):

This folder is located in phone memory. Access to which folders are only in the emulator.

Comment: Thanks natali, thats what i wanted to know.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes @idiottiger is right. Your Phone needs to be rooted for that.
But you can test your app in the emulator, and find the data/data/ using the file manager of your eclipse.
There you have access to it.

Then use the squilte plugin to view your database file.